# Avoid rerender in React caused by objects literal : how to do with variables in the object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, render, object-literal

I read in this article [React is Slow, React is Fast: Optimizing React Apps in Practice](https://marmelab.com/blog/2017/02/06/react-is-slow-react-is-fast.html#beware-of-object-literals-in-jsx) that :

> In fact, each time you pass an object literal as prop to a child component, you break purity.

Alright, I got it. So the best to avoid that is to create a variable with the object, and insert this variable in the prop, like that :

```
import React from 'react';

const style = { marginTop: 10 };
const AnyComponent = (props) => (
    <div style={style}>
        ...
    </div>
)
```

But what if the style prop depend on a received prop ? Where should be the object ?
So for instance, I have this component:

```
import React from 'react';

const AnyComponent = (props) => (
    <div style={{ marginTop: props.marginTop }}>
        ...
    </div>
)
```

Is it a good practice to do:

```
import React from 'react';

const style = (marginTop) => ({ marginTop })
const AnyComponent = (props) => (
    <div style={style(props.marginTop)}>
        ...
    </div>
)
```

[EDIT] I forgot to say that most of my components have state, so in that case, is it a good idea to do :

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {

  style = () => ({
    marginTop: this.props.marginTop
  })

  render() {
    return(
      <div style={this.style()}>

      </div>
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: You are overcomplicating things. Do you have a performance problem?

Comment: I actually do : my app is pretty big (much bigger than that), using redux, and one of my deep nested component uses draft-js. I would like to store the EditorState in my redux store for conveniency, but I can't do it now because of performance and too many re-rendering issues making the text editor lagging. I would like to give a shot to this optimization, because I already have done many more (recompose, reselect, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Previously you couldn't do this in functional components (although you could use memoization)
But now by the favor of React hooks, you can do something like this:

```
const AnyComponent = (props) => {
    const style = useMemo(() => ({ marginTop: props.marginTop }), [props.marginTop]);
    <div style={style}>
        ...
    </div>
}
```

And no, you can't use this one:

```
import React from 'react';

const style = (marginTop) => ({ marginTop })
const AnyComponent = (props) => (
    <div style={style(props.marginTop)}>
        ...
    </div>
)
```

Because it also creates a new object on every re-render of AnyComponent by calling the style function each time.

Comment: `useMemo` returns memoized value, not a function that returns it. The suggestion with `getStyle` would be true for `useCallback`.

Comment: @estus Thankyou so much for your comment. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could create your variable in your component, as follow:

```
import React from 'react';

const AnyComponent = (props) => {
 // if props.marginTop is an object
 const style = props.marginTop;

 return (
    <div style={style}>
        ...
    </div>
)};
```

Comment: Is this creating a new `style` variable each time though? The previous `style` and current `style` object would have different addresses, right?

Answer (score 1):

An object can be memoized with `useMemo` hook:

```
const AnyComponent = (({ marginTop }) => (
    const style = useMemo(() => ({ marginTop }), [marginTop]);
    <div style={style}>
        ...
    </div>
)
```

Since `useMemo` is intended for expensive calculations and has its own overhead, this may be considered premature optimization for `div` case.

Comment: thanks for your reply, what do you suggest for class components ? I edited my post with a proposal, what do you think about it ?

Comment: `useMemo` is specific to functional components. You can use general-purpose memoizer like Lodash. As I mentioned, this optimization doesn't make much sense for <div>. As for class components with custom props, a better thing is to make them responsible for rerender decisions instead and use shouldComponentUpdate.

Comment: @estus Can you please tell what expensive calculations are needed for it?

Comment: @EddieCooro Some function that takes considerable amount of CPU or RAM, e.g. complex object object.